# RESVT Bulk Update

Tags: rest, stateless, workfront-api

I had a question last month about POSTing to Workfront's RESVT field. Since then, I've completed my database to pull all of our department's Leave Calendar data and feed it into Workfront's API as POST methods; however, I've discovered a new problem.

Every time I add a new RESVT event to a user with an existing RESVT event, it deletes the previous event before it saves the new event. I've looked into submitting a bulk edit using the bulk editing format to get all of the events for a user online all at once like this:

```
https://sosprojects.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0
/5b6b72b5007d93b00b00dda361398cad?method=put&updates=
[
{
objCode:”RESVT”,
startDate:”2018-08-20T00:00:00:000-0700”,
endDate:”2018-08-23T00:00:00:000-700”
},
{
objCode:”RESVT”,
startDate:”2018-09-20T00:00:00:000-0700”,
endDate:”2018-09-23T00:00:00:000-0700”
}
]
&sessionID=209055d209f94662b32ac50175b34bc7
```

Which Workfront "accepts" (it doesn't spit out an error code), but it still only saves the last RESVT event (e.g. 9/20 - 9/23).

I've tried using PUT to edit an existing RESVT event, but each RESVT event will only accept one start and one end date so it collapses those attempts into one extra long event.

I know the time-off calendar can manually create multiple RESVT events per user, but I can't figure out how to replicate that feat with my http methods. The calendar always creates new RESVT events for every event logged whenever I add a new event to it; so I think it is doing something like the bulk POST I tried at the top, so why can't my method do the same thing?

Comment: How are you making this call? JavaScript or postman ? did you miss providing HTTP method. try to put mode snippets of code

Answer (score 0):

The API docs don't show update as a valid method for the RESVT object. Just modify the fields directly for the specific object you want to update. Do you know its ID?

```
PUT https://<url>.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/RESVT/<ID of the reserved time you want to edit>?userID=abc1234,startDate=<date>,endDate=<date>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I actually want to post since I'm trying to create a new RESVT I tried:

/attask/api/v9.0/RESVT=
{
"userID":"abc1234",
"startDate":"2018-08-20T00:00:00:000-0700",
"endDate":"2018-08-23T00:00:00:000-0700"
}
just now and got the error IllegalArgumentException null objCode               Do I need to include an ID for the REVT object or should that automatically populate?

Comment: I got it working with POST https://<url>.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/RESVT?userID=<id>&startDate=2018-08-20T00:00:00:000-0700&endDate=2018-08-23T00:00:00:000-0700&apiKey=<key>

Comment: Thanks! Yeah just needed to include method call method=post and it ran fine